# How to change the update-URL of a Silverlight OOB application

Tags: silverlight, updates, silverlight-oob

Once a Silverlight application has been installed as an out-of-browser application, I know I can update it by calling the `Application.Current.CheckAndDownloadUpdateAsync()` method. This will check the URL where the XAP was originally downloaded and update if necessary.

But what if, somewhere in the future, I would want or need to change the url of the XAP? The domain name changes, the location on my site, etc.

Is there a way of indicating where the OOB application should check for the update?

Now I know of the `/origin` property, but as far as I know, there's no way to set this when you let the user just install it by clicking on a button on your site (or right clicking in the application). Also, I don't know of a way of *changing* it at a certain point in time. Other than letting the user do it manually, that is. But that's not very user-friendly.

If it is entirely not possible, maybe a redirect could do the trick?

So is there a way to programmatically define/change the URL of a XAP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not change origin url for installed OOB application. Not without asking user to uninstall and re-install application from new location. It is not all that user friendly, but it is transparent to the user.

Ideally origin url should not change during life time of the application. Using server side url rewriting (maybe redirecting too) should be fine if you would like to move xap file around. If changing domain name is unavoidable you could push an update to the users that reminds them that application moved to different domain and it needs to be re-installed.

Comment: Okay, that could work. But if they uninstall the application, they'd lose all data also, right (just checking)? Redirecting or rewriting does seem the most viable and user-friendly option.

Comment: Yeah, isolated storage data will be lost in re-install process. You could offer users an option to export/import their settings to file in the documents folder (for example) or to remote storage (dropbox, skydrive, etc).